# I need some guidance on rewriting a regular expression in racket/scheme. I am trying to do this r' [_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]* '

Tags: regex, scheme, racket, lexer

CODE IN RACKET:

```
(:: (:seq(:or(:* "_")(:+ upper-case)(:+ lower-case)) (:* "_")(:* upper-case)(:* lower-case)(:* digit))) (token-SYM lexeme)
```

This regular expression does not seem to work for test cases such as:

```
_ASFFDsfafg_03043435  or  adfdSFISDFIOON_asfDFOIN3055
```

it seems to not work correctly with the underscore, it seems to think anytime it gets an underscore its the start of a new token. 
 my program is a lexer scanning each character and the regular expression is to define behavior for a  SYM token  which is a symbol token.

Comment: the racket code above has an underscore before both (:* upper-case) sections but did not put it in when I posted for some reason.

Comment: I figured it out.  I used a (char-set  string) or lexer macro instead.   additionally (char-range char char) functions. I found them just in time.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I think you might just be looking for

```
#px"[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*"
```

As e.g.:

```
(regexp-match? #px"[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*" "_ASFFDsfafg_03043435")
(regexp-match? #px"[_A-Za-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*" "adfdSFISDFIOON_asfDFOIN3055")
```

... which both evaluate to true.

More generally, Racket supports full perl regexps, AFAIK.

I see that you may be looking for support from the parser library; I'm not sure what the status of racket regexps in this case is.

Comment: Unfortunately the regexp-match? Functions I couldn’t get to work with the Lexer library. I did try that briefly but wouldn’t work. The lexer library has functions  for regex are like (:: ) or (:?) (:*) (:+) where the ? * + all have same meta characteristics as python or bash.  But what I ended up doing to solve my particular problem was (define Lex- abbrev sym-set1 (char-set “_AlluppercaseAllLowercase”)  then defined another set like it for other half of regex , then used function like( ::(:+ sym-set) (:* sym-set2))  and it seemed to work!!! Probably could be done in a better way though!

Comment: Right, I'm familiar with the parser library. I bet there's a way to make them play nice together, but you'd probably have to mess around in the guts of the parser library, sigh.

Comment: I guess I'd hate to have someone read this question without any idea about the parser library and come away thinking Racket doesn't have support for the standard regexp syntax.

Comment: yes! I thought that too. I wasn't sure if I was going to be able to represent my regular expression I needed in racket, but then I thought, hey, racket is a popular language for creating other languages, so there has to be away to do this.     I am not really all that familiar with lexers or parsers.  this is the first time I have tried playing with them. I made a program in python using ply, and in racket.  racket seems much less intuitive however.  I think its just because I am knew to the functional programming style though.

Comment: No no no... I think you should know that the "parser" framework is a faithful implementation of lex and yacc, two wonderful tools from the early eighties, written in C. As such, the issues you're experiencing are probably less likely to be issues with functional programming, and rather simply issues with the lex and yacc framework.